# How to create a form for summing values and evaluate result using if statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a form where I can calculate an average in two areas, based on two inputs. Then I would like to average my two calculated averages ( Average Benefits paid to Highly Compensated EE's / Average Benefits paid to Non-Highly Compensated EE's). My code onkeyup is broken somewhere during this calculation. Lastly, I'd like to perform an IF statement for id="TestResult" if   ( Average Benefits paid to Highly Compensated EE's / Average Benefits paid to Non-Highly Compensated EE's)>= 55% then "Pass" else "Fail". I'm new to java so I could really use the help in fixing my code, and getting this IF statement working. Any recommendations?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input").keyup(function() {
        var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
        var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
        $("#result").val(val1 / val2);
        var val3 = +$(".value3").val();
        var val4 = +$(".value4").val();
        $("#result2").val((val3/val4));
        $("#result3").val(((val3+val4)/(val1+val2))*100);



    });
});
```

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <td>Non-taxable benefits paid to Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input value1">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Number of Highly Compensated Employees:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input value2">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Average Benefits paid to Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Non-taxable benefits paid to Non-Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input value3">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Number of Non-Highly Compensated Employees included*:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input value4">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Average Benefits paid to Non-Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result2">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Average Benefit Percentage Ratio:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result3">
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Result:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"  id="TestResult" style='overflow:hidden; border:0px solid #000000; width:80%'>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a Java question?

Comment: Javascript is to Java as Carpet is to Car. Very different.

Comment: Java **IS NOT** JavaScript.

Comment: I apologize, I'm really trying to get this done for work, but I am by no means a programmer. I appreciate the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input").keyup(function() {
        var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
        var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
        $("#result").val((val1 / val2).toFixed(2));
        var val3 = +$(".value3").val();
        var val4 = +$(".value4").val();
        $("#result2").val((val3/val4).toFixed(2));
        $("#result3").val(((val3+val4)/(val1+val2)*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
       
       var result = $("#result").val()/$("#result2").val();
       
       if(result >= 0.55){
          $("#TestResult").val((result * 100).toFixed(2) + "%" + "Pass");
        } else {
          $("#TestResult").val("FAIL");
        }
          
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Non-taxable benefits paid to Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="input value1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of Highly Compensated Employees:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="input value2">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Average Benefits paid to Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Non-taxable benefits paid to Non-Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="input value3">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of Non-Highly Compensated Employees included*:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="input value4">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Average Benefits paid to Non-Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result2">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Average Benefit Percentage Ratio:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result3">
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Result:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"  id="TestResult" style='overflow:hidden; border:0px solid #000000; width:80%'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Is it possible to format the first two outputs to be currency (dollar sign and two decimal places) and the final result value to be a percent (% sign and two decimal places)? Ideally it'd like the first three calculated values to be dollars and the final result to be a % with two decimals.

Comment: Turn every number to variables, add dollar sign as string, and use toFixed(2) method to float the decimal. e.g $("#result").val("$" + (val1 / val2).toFixed(2));

Comment: Thanks, formatting is working. The IF statement is not however. Should be Pass if the average benefit percentage ratio is greater than 55, but it currently says "Fail". I'm having trouble locating the bug.